# Adding label for indicator on right axis

Tags: pine-script

Im currently coding an indicator in Pinescript and am having issues getting the static horizontal line of the indicator to show a label on the right side axis for price.  If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be great.  Here is a snippet of code for reference.

```
    // fs line and label
    var line fs_line = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, 
    extend = extend.both,  color = color.green, style = line.style_dotted, width = 1)
    line.set_xy1(id = fs_line, x = bar_index - p, y = fs)
    line.set_xy2(id = fs_line, x = bar_index, y = fs)

    var label fs_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.rgb(0, 
    0, 0, 100), textcolor = color.green, style = label.style_label_center, text = " First 
    Support\n  \n", size = size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)
    label.set_xy(id = fs_label, x = bar_index+(15), y = fs)
```

Answer (score 0):

line() functions won't generate a label that appears on the y axis the same way the plot() function does. If you need to display the line's value, your best approach is to use your label and add the price information to it:

```
label.set_text(id = fs_label, text = "Support : " + tostring(fs) + "\n  \n")
```

Comment: How would i add the price info to it?  The price info isnt static so it would have to be updated.  Is there a variable to pull current price of the indicator line?

Comment: Or i guess i should ask.  Can this be converted to use a plot() function and still get the same results so i can have the label?

Comment: The above should update the price when the levels change. `fs` is one of the calculated levels correct? So when that changes, the text/price displayed from `tostring(fs)` will also change. You could of course use `plot(fs)` instead, but your chart will then have all historical levels not just the current value of `fs`